# Error in utf8 encoding while creating object. Normal when update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, ckeditor

Sorry for my bad english. I have a very strange bug. When I create an instance of a *Task*
 model with utf8 content, the stored *content* in database is not what it was input. The *content* field is created using ckeditor. Here it is:

- What user input: `Lưu`
- The params: `{"task"=>
  {"name"=>"Store",
  "description"=>"Store",
  "price"=>"10000",
  "content"=>"<p>\r\n\tLưu</p>\r\n"},
  "commit"=>"Create Task",
  "action"=>"create",
  "controller"=>"tasks"}`
- The instance in memory: `#<Task id: nil, name: "Store", description: "Store", price: 10000, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, content: "<p>\r\n\tLưu</p>\r\n">`
- What is stored: `#<Task id: 10, name: "Store", description: "Store", price: 10000, created_at: "2012-05-22 03:47:11", updated_at: "2012-05-22 03:47:11", content: "\\x3c703e0d0a094cc6b0753c2f703e0d0a">`

However, the strangest part is that when I edit that model and save it, the content is stored as it is inputed.

Here is my migration for the content column:

```
class AddContentToTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change                   
    add_column :tasks, :content, :text
  end
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
  def update
    @task.update_attributes!(params[:task])
  end

  def create                   
    binding.pry                
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])   
    @task.user = current_user  
    @task.save                 
    redirect_to tasks_path
  end
```

When I debug (using binding.pry), I see that the @task.content is correct. However, after @task.save, the last created Task's content (Task.last) is not.

UPDATE 1: My database.yml

```
development:                   
  adapter: postgresql          
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false             
  database: crowd              
  pool: 5
  username: username          
  password: password           
  host: localhost

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: crowd-test
  pool: 5
  username: username          
  password: password           
  host: localhost
```

My schema.rb content.

```
# encoding: UTF-8

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120519133158) do

     create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "description"
        t.integer  "price"
        t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.integer  "task_type_id"
        t.text     "content"
        t.date     "expired_at"
      end
end
```

My schema info from postgre

```
                                   List of databases
    Name    |   Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 crowd      | username  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 crowd-test | username  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

UPDATE 2: Instead of using `@task = Task.new(params[:task])`, I set all the attribute of the @task instance by myself. The stored content is also correct.

Comment: put your database.yml and your schema. Also, check the collation of the database. 90% of the time is a wrong collation.

Comment: I have update my question with databae.yml and my schema. The database info from postgre says that my collation is en_US.UTF-8.